# poweredge r220 ubuntu 16.04 idrac black screen in virtual console

Tags: dell-poweredge, ubuntu-16.04

i trying to run a virtual console on a dell r220 
with ubuntu 14 it works fine
if i install ubuntu 16 or upgrade to it i get a black screen in the console
instantly after the bios initialization

i dont get this why is it not working do i not supposed to see whats on the screen of the machine independent from the OS is this not meant for emergency cases whet the OS is irresponsible
if the os is working i can ssh in and i dont need idarc and if the os isnt working
why would just the part of it work which is needed for idarc to work

EDIT 
i forgot to mention that the system works mean i can log in through ssh

Comment: Ubuntu does this on a _lot_ of servers, and even a few desktops. There's a workaround but I don't have it handy, since I avoid distributions like that...

Comment: Maybe a problem with the splash screen. Try disabling it. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: thanks @sfk this line out of the link you provided solved the problem # The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

Comment: Make sure serial output process is running

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues like the one you are describing when you attach a monitor to the server that supports resolutions beyond those supported by the iDRAC

See my response here: https://askubuntu.com/a/925487/235786